# Saving large objects to file

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on a project in Objective-c where I need to work with large quantities of data stored in an `NSDictionary` (it's around max ~2 gigs in ram). After all the computations that I preform on it, it seems like it would be quicker to save/load the data when needed (versus re-parsing the original file).

So I started to look into saving large amount of data. I've tried using `NSKeyedUnarchiver` and `[NSDictionary writeToFile:atomically:]`, but both failed with malloc errors (Can not allocate ____ bytes).

I've looked around SO, Apple's Dev forums and Google, but was unable to find anything. I'm wondering if it might be better to create the file bit-by-bit instead of all at once, but I can't anyway to add to an existing file. I'm not completely opposed to saving with a bunch of small files, but I would much rather use one big file.

Thanks!

Edited to include more information: I'm not sure how much overhead `NSDictionary` gives me, as I don't take all the information from the text files. I have a 1.5 gig file (of which I keep ~1/2), and it turns out to be around 900 megs through 1 gig in ram. There will be some more data that I need to add eventually, but it will be constructed with references to what's already loaded into memory - it shouldn't double the size, but it may come close.

The data is all serial, and could be separated in storage, but needs to all be in memory for execution. I currently have integer/string pairs, and will eventually end up with string/strings pairs (with all the values also being a key for a different set of strings, so the final storage requirements will be the same strings that I currently have, plus a bunch of references).

In the end, I will need to associate ~3 million strings with some other set of strings. However, the only important thing is the relationship between those strings - I could hash all of them, but `NSNumber` (as `NSDictionary` needs objects) might give me just as much overhead.

Comment: How much of the data is data, and how much is overhead from NSDictionary?

With this much data, it might be worth considering writing some hand-crafted code to manage it all.

Can you provide some context? Is the data hierarchical or serial? Is it separable or integrated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSDictionary isn't going to give you the scalable storage that you're looking for, at least not for persistence. You should implement your own type of data structure/serialisation process.

Have you considered using an embedded sqllite database? Then you can process the data but perhaps only loading a fragment of the data structure at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, rebuilding your application in 64-bit mode will give you a much larger heap space.

If that's not an option for you, you'll need to create your own data structure and define your own load/save routines that don't allocate as much memory.

Comment: Oops. For some reason u was thinking 64-bit GUI was a 10.6 feature. I've edited my answer.